Is every connection locally flat for an other connection?
Consider a $C^{\infty}$ connection $d_A = d+A$ on the unit ball $B^n\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Does there exists another connection $d_{\tilde{A}} = d+\tilde{A}$ such that $d_{\tilde{A}} A = 0$? That is to say, can we find a second connection which makes $A$ flat?
I am interested in the local version, that is to say, I can reduce the radius of the ball if necessary. Hence, I imagine that there should not be any topological issue.
We can enlarge the setting a little bit: given a section $s$ of a vector bundle over $B^n$, can we find a connection $\nabla$ on this vector bundle such that $\nabla s=0$?

Nonzero sections of vector bundles are clearly identified locally by local vector bundle isomorphism, so there is no local obstruction to making one local section parallel for some connection.

That sounds reasonable. But I do not really understand how can we find the right connection.

This was already explained by Ben McKay, so I am only elaborating on the point made. Let $\mathscr{M}$ be a connected smooth manifold and $E = \mathbf{R}^k \times \mathscr{M}$ be a trivial vector bundle. If $s_0 \in \Gamma(E)$ is nowhere vanishing, then there exists a smooth bundle isomorphism $\tau \in \Gamma(\operatorname{End} E)$ such that $\tau s_0$ is constant. This suggests we define the connection $\mathrm{d}^\tau = \tau^{-1} \circ \mathrm{d} \circ \tau$. Indeed, as a composition of $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps it is also $\mathbb{R}$-linear, and for any $g \in C^\infty(\mathscr{M})$ and $s \in \Gamma(E)$,
$$
\mathrm{d}^\tau (gs) = \tau^{-1}  \mathrm{d}(\tau g s) = \tau^{-1} \big(\mathrm{d}g \otimes \tau s + g\hspace{1pt} \mathrm{d}(\tau s) \big) = \mathrm{d}g \otimes s + g \hspace{1pt}\mathrm{d}^\tau(s),
$$
so the Leibniz rule holds. By construction, $s_0$ is parallel with respect to $\mathrm{d}^\tau$, and the same holds true for $\mathrm{d}^{\alpha \tau}$, where $\alpha \in \Gamma(\mathrm{GL}(\mathbf{R}^k) \times \mathscr{M})$ is any constant section.
On the other hand, if $s_0$ vanishes at a point, then a connection for which $s_0$ is parallel exists if and only if $s_0$ is identically zero (which implies $s_0$ is parallel with respect to any connection).
